# Can all redeemers in a transaction be retrieved at once?

Tags: plutus, redeemer

In the case of multiple datums and redeemers provided in a transaction, I see that TxInfo contains all datum in `txInfoData   :: [(DatumHash, Datum)]` but not all redeemers are included.

```
    data TxInfo = TxInfo
    { txInfoInputs      :: [TxInInfo] -- ^ Transaction inputs
    , txInfoOutputs     :: [TxOut] -- ^ Transaction outputs
    , txInfoFee         :: Value -- ^ The fee paid by this transaction.
    , txInfoMint        :: Value -- ^ The 'Value' minted by this transaction.
    , txInfoDCert       :: [DCert] -- ^ Digests of certificates included in this transaction
    , txInfoWdrl        :: [(StakingCredential, Integer)] -- ^ Withdrawals
    , txInfoValidRange  :: POSIXTimeRange -- ^ The valid range for the transaction.
    , txInfoSignatories :: [PubKeyHash] -- ^ Signatures provided with the transaction, attested that they all signed the tx
    , txInfoData        :: [(DatumHash, Datum)]
    , txInfoId          :: TxId
    -- ^ Hash of the pending transaction (excluding witnesses)
    } deriving stock (Generic, Haskell.Show, Haskell.Eq)
```

**Is it possible to retrieve all redeemers at once ?**

Answer (score 1):

***This was Lars response to this question in the ppp Q&A on 25/Jan/22. Recording timestamp 0:43:17***

> *You cant retrieve all redeemers at once,  You can only see your own
> redeemer,*
>
> *You are always in the context of validating your specific input,
> There maybe one or more script inputs, but for each script input the
> validator is run, and it gets the datum, redeemer and context.*
>
> *The context is always more or less the same in each case except the
> context also knows which inputs you are presently validating and you
> get the datum and redeemer belonging to that input (the datum
> belonging to the output you are consuming and the redeemer for the
> input).*
>
> *So I think you can only see the current redeemer, the one belonging to
> the input you are currently validating.*
>
> *I may be wrong but that's how I think how it is, not only you can't
> retrieve them at once but you can't see them at all*